# Missing propertys on mongoose query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am using MongoDB, Mongoose in combination with typescript. My problem is following:

I have defined an model like this:

```
export default conn.model<AdminInterface & Document>('Admin', adminSchema)

export interface AdminInterface {
  email: string,
  password: string,
  role: string,
  created: Date,
  author: {
    name: string,
    bio: string,
    githubUrl: string,
    stackoverflowLink: string,
    twitterLink: string,
    image: string,
    image_webp: string,
  },
}
```

It throws no error.

Now i want to do a simple query like:

```
import { AdminInterface } from "../model/admin"
export function getAdmin(): Promise<AdminInterface | null> {
  return Admin.findOne({ role: 'admin' }, { password: 0 })
}
```

But it throws me that error:

> Type 'DocumentQuery<AdminInterface & Document, AdminInterface & Document, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'AdminInterface': email, password, role, created, author

What i am doing wrong? How do i tell the `.findOne` method how my response would look like?

Comment: `findOne` is async, maybe are you returning the `Promise` and the promise fields not match with your interface?

Comment: @J.F. yes its returning an promise i tried now `Promise<AdminInterface>` doesnt help. I tried `Promise<any>` nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the solution.

I have to add `.exec()` on the end and the error dissapeared:

```
import { AdminInterface } from "../model/admin"
export function getAdmin(): Promise<AdminInterface | null> {
  return Admin.findOne({ role: 'admin' }, { password: 0 }).exec()
}
```

I dont know if this is the way to go. However i will use it like this